# New Gtk4 App. model : CLI positional arguments

Tags: python, gtk4

I'm trying to understand how to define CLI arguments using [the new Gtk4 model](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/method.Application.add_main_option.html) but I only managed to define non-positional / flagged arguments:

```
# (...)
class MyApp(Adw.Application):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(
            *args,
            application_id="org.example.myapp",
            flags=Gio.ApplicationFlags.HANDLES_COMMAND_LINE | 
                        Gio.ApplicationFlags.HANDLES_OPEN,
            **kwargs
        )
        self.connect('activate', self.on_activate)

        self.add_main_option(
            "test",
            ord("t"),  # <= This works
            GLib.OptionFlags.NONE,
            GLib.OptionArg.NONE,
            "Command line test",
            None,
        )

        self.add_main_option(
            "file",
            0,  # <= This doesn't
            GLib.OptionFlags.NONE,
            GLib.OptionArg.FILENAME,
            "File to load",
            None,
        )

    def on_activate(self, app):
        self.win = MainWindow(application=app)
        self.win.present()

    def on_quit(self, action, param):
        self.quit()

    def do_open(self, action, param):
        print("Now what")

    def do_command_line(self, command_line):
        options = command_line.get_options_dict()
        options = options.end().unpack()

        if "test" in options:
            print("Argument:  %s" % options["test"])

        if "file" in options: # <= And so this never fires
            print("Argument: %s" % options["file"])

        self.activate()
        return 0

app = MyApp()
app.run(sys.argv)
```

Of course I tried every combination of [OptionArg](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/enum.OptionArg.html) and [OptionFlag](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/flags.OptionFlags.html) constants.
This is really hard to google for, given that this API replaced `argparse`, that  itself (If I'm not mistaking) replaced something else before, so there is **a lot** of stale documentation out there.

I **can** get the arguments by using

```
argv = command_line.get_arguments()
self.loaded_file = argv[1]
```

But that is not right, it's totally bypassing the GtkApplication logic, and the help is not right:

```
# ./fwomaj -h                                 
Usage:
  fwomaj [OPTION…]

Help Options:
  -h, --help                 Show help options
  --help-all                 Show all help options
  --help-gapplication        Show GApplication options

Application Options:
  -t, --test                 Command line test
  --file                     Video file to load
```

It should say

```
Usage:
  fwomaj [OPTION…] FILE
(...)
  -t, --test                 Command line test
  FILE                       Video file to load
```

So there is really something that I'm missing there.

Answer (score 0):

I got [the solution / answer](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/new-gtk4-app-model-cli-positional-arguments/12029/4?u=yphil) on the official [Gtk community channel](https://discourse.gnome.org):

```
class MyApp(Adw.Application):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(
            *args,
            application_id="org.example.myapp",
            flags=Gio.ApplicationFlags.HANDLES_OPEN,
            **kwargs
        )
        self.connect('activate', self.on_activate)

        self.add_main_option(
            "test",
            ord("t"),
            GLib.OptionFlags.NONE,
            GLib.OptionArg.NONE,
            "Command line test",
            None,
        )

        self.set_option_context_parameter_string("FILE")
        self.set_option_context_summary("  FILE is The video file to load")
        self.set_option_context_description("where FILE is The video file to load")
```

Notice the flag change in the constructor ; Also [apparently](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/new-gtk4-app-model-cli-positional-arguments/12029/6?u=yphil), file opening capabilities don't need extended documentation, just a `app [OPTIONS] FILE` mention in the `--help`.